# Is there an optimal way to create futureproofed term-less relationships in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm just learning Neo4j and want to create a system that allows me to have Topics that each could have parents or children, but it's not always obvious if it's a parent or a child, and the relationships are not always the same type.

If you look at Neo4j's example [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/) it uses this code:

```
(:Person {name: string})-[:ACTED_IN {roles: [string]}]->(:Movie {title: string, released: number})
```

This works when you know it's movies. In this case, the node is of `Movie` type. If you're creating something that today has movies but tomorrow has a totally different topic, like CEOs then `movie` is no longer relevant as well as the relationship `ACTED_IN`. How do people generally handle these scenarios when they want their code to be managable as their "topics" or node types change, especially when the node types could just be more generic `thing`s from the start.

Maybe something like:

`Tom Hanks IS_CHILD_OF Forrest Gump` instead of  `Tom Hanks ACTED_IN Forrest Gump`

but how do you determine directionality of this one now that the relationship name is so generic? Is an actor the child of their movie, or is the movie now a child of the actor?

The main question I have is, how can I futureproof so I have a generic `thing` instead of `movie` or `ceo` or `hot_sauce` nodes. So if tomorrow the topic is CEOs, you have `Tim Cook IS_CHILD_OF Apple` or something along those lines?

Also, is this just extremely non-performant? If so, then if the names of the node types and relationships are extremely dynamic, how do you track those and know what to query, and when?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, relationship types should always be as specific as possible, thus helping Neo4j traversing only as little data as necessary. Traversals, ideally, just need to filter through node labels and relationship types. Continuing your example, would your dataset really evolve from movies to CEOs? If not, I'd personally make sure the queries presently do their job well first, before worrying about possibly unknown future details.

Comment: I think they could. Just imagining a scenario where I want to maintain nodes for all types of "things", a thing could be movies today but types of hot sauces tomorrow. With that, it would become unmanageable to maintain a seemingly infinite number of relationship types. I think?

Comment: If your data could become anything, then yes, I agree, it could be hard to model. But how realistic is that scenario? And if your dataset changes completely, the database would not be the only concern (apps would need to change, pre-sales would need to change their pitches...)

Comment: It's a good question but think the idea is a bit off. What's being developed is something where you can interact with anything, so it's similar to Facebook Pages where you can follow them but uniquely you can basically say another page is related to/child of another. If Facebook were to implement Pages, where pages could be anything but then you could connect any two pages, how do you think you might connect those? For example, if Tesla wanted to connect its FB Page to SpaceX's or to Moon or to Elon Musk, in that case you have two companies, 1 place, and 1 celebrity, but they're all "Things"?

Answer (score 1):

Future-proof is a dangerous path to go down in my opinion :-)
Nevertheless, if the system you are building is generic then there must be some core concepts that you model upon. Topics that have a parent-child relationship, or Pages that relate to each other. Those are good enough to model upon since you can test the model against the questions you ask of it.

With graph modelling, the questions/use cases come before the model, so I'd start there- what do you want the graph to answer? Examples: Which pages are related to Tesla? Or, how is Topic A and Topic B related? Without these questions, your graph model can range from somewhat adequate to non-performant to fits-the-case.
Once you have the questions, then the entities/nodes should start to jump out at you immediately, as well as the relationships.

The closest real-world example I can think of is the [POLE model](https://neo4j.com/blog/graph-technology-pole-position-law-enforcement/) that bases itself on four types of concepts- Person, Object, Location, Event. Everything in this domain is slotted into one of those four. This lends the model a somewhat "generic" flavour whilst still allowing for sensible queries such as Which events occurred at that Location involving this Person and that Object.

You could further abstract this away to a single node type called Entity and a single relationship type called RELATED or similar but then you need to build in a whole layer of metadata to make sense of what this structure really indicates. Your database would become nothing more than a storage of linked pieces of information and you'd delegate the business logic to the application, forming queries based on the metadata. Maybe this is what you're after.

In terms of performance, it would be very hard to say because the whole graph looks the same- perhaps you'd have very dense nodes, perhaps you'd have to traverse every relationship from those dense nodes and filter them out by properties. Indexes would not be of much use if you had only one label.
So in essence, this model is definitely possible, but if that's the path you're going down then it would be worth examining what the graph database brings to your domain/application to be certain that these tradeoffs are worth it.